# problema com setinterval

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou tendo um problema em um chat que estou desenvolvendo, ele funciona assim do lado direito tenho uma lista de contatos para eu iniciar o chat e essa lista esta dentro de uma função `carregarContatos()` que esta dentro de `setInterval()`.

Para atualizar essa lista de contatos, clicando em um contato eu passo um `idChat` para outra função `abrirConversa(idChat)` que alimenta uma `DIV` que vai me trazer as conversas daquele `idChat` passado como parâmetro.

O problema é que utilizei o `setInterval()` para ficar recarregando minhas mensagens da conversa, ai quando eu clico em outro contato para abrir outra conversa, a conversa antiga não é limpada e acaba sendo adicionada com a conversa nova que eu abri, ficando piscando a tela alternando entre as duas conversas e assim vai, se eu clicar em um terceiro contato adiciona a conversa dele também ai fica mostrando as 3 conversas piscando a tela.

```
  // monta a linha na tabela apos um novo produto ter sido cadastrado
function montarLinhaContatos(c){
  let linha = "<li>" +
        "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='abrirConversa("+c.ID_CHAT+")'><img src='"+c.FOTO+"' alt='user-img' class='img-circle'> <span>" + c.NOME + "<small class='text-success'>online</small></span></a>"+
        "</li>";
    return linha;                            
}

// chama a api que carregas os dados dos produtos cadastrados via objeto json
function carregarContatos(){
    $('#msg').html('carregando contatos...');
    $.getJSON('/carregarContato', function(contatos){
            $('#msg').hide();
            $('#lista-contatos').html('');
            for (let i = 0; i < contatos.length; i++) {
                linhaContato = montarLinhaContatos(contatos[i]);
                $('#lista-contatos').append(linhaContato);
            }
    });
}
function montarConversaRecebida(mr){
    let linhaMsg = "<li>" +
    "<div class='chat-image'> <img alt='male' src='"+mr.FOTO+"'> </div>"+
    "<div class='chat-body'>"+
        "<div class='chat-text'>"+
            "<h4>"+mr.NOME+"</h4>"+
            "<p>"+mr.CONTEUDO+"</p>"+
            "<b>10.00 am</b> </div>"+
        "</div>"+
    "</li>";
    return linhaMsg;
}

function montarConversaEnviada(me){
    let linhaMsg1 = "<li class='odd'>" +
    "<div class='chat-image'> <img alt='male' src='"+me.FOTO+"'> </div>"+
    "<div class='chat-body'>"+
        "<div class='chat-text'>"+
            "<h4>"+me.NOME+"</h4>"+
            "<p>"+me.CONTEUDO+"</p>"+
            "<b>10.00 am</b> </div>"+
        "</div>"+
    "</li>";
    return linhaMsg1;
}

function abrirConversa(id) {
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#alertaC').html('Carregando conversa...');
        $('#mensagens').html('');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'carregarMensagem/'+id,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#alertaC').html('');
                $('#mensagens').html('');
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        linhaMsg1 = montarConversaRecebida(data[i]);
                        linhaMsg2 = montarConversaEnviada(data[i]);

                        if(data[i].CODG_USUARIO == data[i].CODG_USUARIO_DESTINATARIO){
                            $('#mensagens').append(linhaMsg2);
                        } else {
                            $('#mensagens').append(linhaMsg1);
                        }
                    }
            }
        });
    }, 500);
} 

$(function(){

    setInterval(() => {
        carregarContatos();
    }, 3000);
})
```

Comment: Não use setInterval com Ajax, use setTimeout. Talvez tb vc esteja repetindo id's, não?

Comment: acho que não porque a cada click eu passo um id diferente, la na minha função montarlinha contato eu chamo no onclick abrirConversa(idchat) passando o id do chat

Comment: voce teria algum exemplo com esse timeout ? pois nunca fiz algo parecido...

Comment: Já postei várias resposta com esse problema do setInterval. Basicamente seria vc colocar o Ajax dentro de uma função, chamar essa função, e no success chamar novamente a função. Isso cria um loop onde o Ajax só é chamado quando o Ajax for processado. Ao usar setInterval, vc irá chamar o Ajax seguidas vezes, é até ok, mas isso poderá gerar um gargalo no navegador pois uma requisição poderá ser chamada antes da anterior ter sido completada. Isso pode até travar o navegador. Com setTimeout isso não pode acontecer pq cada requisição será chamada de forma ordenada.

Comment: Vou deixar [este artigo do John Resig](https://johnresig.com/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) que explica muito bem o uso de `setInterval` e `setTimeout` nesses casos... Basicamente, se o seu código do `setInterval` demorar mais tempo do que o intervalo entre uma execução e outra, a pilha de execução vai crescer infinitamente e seu navegador vai parar de funcionar.

Comment: Então é só dentro do sucesso da minha função abrirConversa(id) no sucesso do meu ajax eu chamo minha própria funçao ? e troco o setinterval pelo setTimeout